# Database information embed discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I successfully connected my Discord Bot to my sql database. But right now the data I receive from the database is only getting logged in my console but I wanna change that. I want to make an embed with information from the database and fill the values with the information from the database. I tried to do that but it's giving me an error and I don't know what to change in the embed so it works properly. The database looks like [this](https://prnt.sc/1xq9v0k)

MySQL connection:

```js
connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM`player_count`', function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

The data that is getting logged:

```js
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    cop_count: '0',
    medic_count: '0',
    civ_count: '1'
  }
]
```

The embed I tried to make:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'info')) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'private',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'User',
    password: 'private',
    database: 'test',
    charset: 'utf8mb4',
  });

  connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM`player_count`', function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      const serverembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

        .setTitle('Info:')
        .setThumbnail('png')
        .setColor('GOLD')
        .addFields(
          { name: '', value: 'cop_count', result, inline: true },
          { name: '', inline: 'medic_count', result, inline: true },
          { name: '', value: 'civ_count', result, inline: true },
        )
        .setTimestamp();

      message.channel.send({ embeds: [serverembed] });
    });
  });
}
```

The error code i'm getting:

```js
C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
    at Function.verifyString (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:413:41)
    at Function.normalizeField (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:441:19)
    at C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:462:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:461:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:283:42)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Bot\Bot v13\index.js:57:14)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Bot\Bot v13\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}
```

Comment: What do you think `result` and `inline` in objects like `{ name: '', value: 'cop_count', result, inline: true }` or `{ name: '', inline: 'medic_count', result, inline: true },` are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely better than your previous attempt to ask this question.

The error `RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.` means that there is an empty field in your embed. If you check the second field, you can see that there is no `value` property, but two `inline`s.

Also, don't forget that the `result` is an array of objects. You'll need to check its length and if it has at least one items, use the properties of `result[0]`:

```js
.addFields(
  { name: '', value: result[0].cop_count, inline: true },
  { name: '', value: result[0].medic_count, inline: true },
  { name: '', value: result[0].civ_count, inline: true },
)
```

Comment: I got another problem. The database information change throughout the day but when I execute the command the embed only shows `0` people even though there are more people and the database shows the right number of people

Comment: Not sure if I can understand you correctly. Could you upload your code on a site like pastebin.com, for example, and post the link here in a comment?

Comment: Also, you can always [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and add more details there.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DK2NbPCj

What i mean is. The Database is used for a Server. Whenever people join or leave the Server the database updates itself. What i want to achieve is, when you use the command that those information from the database are getting read and you see exactly how many people are in a group right now for example in the `cop_count` group. 

My problem is that whenever i use the command the embed never changes. So everytime the embed says that zero people are in a group but when i look in the database 4 people are in the group. So somenthing isn't right in my code.

Comment: Have you checked what the `result` is? Is it updated?

Comment: I thought it was but I guess it's not

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the `value` property correctly in the call to `addValues`.

Try something like this:

```
           .addFields(
                { name: '', value: rows[0].cop_count, inline: true },
                { name: '', value: rows[0].medic_count, inline: true },
                { name: '', value: rows[0].civ_count, inline: true },
            )
```